# Error "terminate called without an active exception" with compiler optimizations turned off (ARM)

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, arm

I am cross compiling (for armv7hv) a simple program that throws two exceptions within an .so file that it loads. 
When I don't have optimizations turned on (`-O0` or missing) the program just terminates with this output when the 2nd exception is thrown:

```
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted
```

The error only occurs when the 2nd exception is thrown from class `ClFoo`'s `Run()` function.
When I turn on optimization (`-O1`) the code executes just fine.

**The program loading the library (filename passed as parameter):**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    void *handle = nullptr;
    long (*func)();
    char *error;
    handle = dlopen(argv[1], RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL);

    func = reinterpret_cast<long(*)()>(dlsym(handle, "FunctionName");
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL) {
        fputs(error, stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    func(nullptr);
}
```

**The library:**

**LibName.h**

```
extern "C" {

long FunctionName();
}
```

**LibName.c**

```
long FunctionName()
{
    printf("ENTER FunctionName()\n");
    try {

        std::exception e;
        throw e;
    }
    catch (std::exception)
    {
        printf("Caught std::exception\n");
    }



    try {
        ClFoo oFoo;
        oFoo.Run();
    }
    catch (std::exception)
    {
        printf("Caught 2nd std::exception\n");
    }
    printf("exit\n")
    return 0;
}

class ClFoo
{
public:
    ClFoo() {};
    ~ClFoo() {};
    void Run() {
        std::exception e;
        throw e;
    };
};
```

I am running out of ideas how to pinpoint this error.

Comment: Shouldn't `FunctionName` accept a pointer argument? Your function has no parameters.

Comment: A few things: The first is that I don't see you using `extern "C"` for the library function, which is needed to inhibit name mangling. Then only check `dllerror` is there's an actual error (i.e. when `dlsym` return a null pointer). Then `NULL` is an old symbolic constant for a null pointer, not a null value or zero (even if it happens to expand to zero). Then the expression `*(void**)(&func) = dlsym(...)` just looks wrong, why not `func = reinterpret_cast<long(*)(void*)>(dlsym(...))`? Then the types of `func` and `FunctionName` in the library are not the same.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was just trying to post a simple version of the program. There's actually an `extern "C" ` in the header of the .so file.

Comment: And if you have different behavior depending on optimization levels (or debug/release builds, etc.) then you most likely have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I revised the code and added your suggestion @Some-programmer-dude. And yes, this is definitely undefined behaviour.